# Photos Places screen - how to show as grid

Tags: macos, photos

I am using Photos on macOS 12.3 choosing the Places album.

I get the map and can expand it so I get a thumbnail photo with a number for the number of photos in that area.

Then I double click on the thumbnail - the first couple of times it switches to a view with all the photos for that area in a grid. However after expanding and going back a few times when I double click on a thumbnail nothing happens. Well the cursor switches from the pointer to a hand so you can drag the map.

How do I reliably get from the Places album to the grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that whenever I click the mouse is not totally still.

Thus if I click once it starts a click and drag.

If I go through contortions to make the mouse totally still then I do get the places expanding.

This is a real accessibility problem,

Answer (score -1):

Double click zooms, single click is enough.

Comment: Single click does nothing for me. (Although it works on first click after restarting the app - then maybe on the second or third location then nothing)